# Fancybox gallery with multimedia

Tags: iframe, fancybox, gallery, multimedia

I have a phpBB board that permits uploads of video along with media. I want to modify an existing phpBB extension for Fancybox, that will permit me to mix media types in a Fancybox gallery.

As a first step, I made a simple page that uses Fancybox to mix media types in a gallery:

http://www.59plymouth.net/fancybox/fancybox.html

I want to fix the following issues with it:

1. I don't want it to autoPlay (although, when I add the autoPlay :
   false attribute, it has no effect;
2. The video controls within the iframe are inaccessible;
3. I see the Youtube video uses the fancybox-media class, and the controls are accessible - but using the fancybox-media class instead of iframe drops it from my gallery;
4. The Fancybox frame for the video is much larger than the video
   itself - I'd like it to autosize, just as with the images.

Any help? Thanks in advance...

Dan

Comment: OK, what I've learned:

1) You have to include jquery.fancybox-media.js for the fancybox-media class to work!  D'Oh...

2) If I use the Youtube example in a gallery, the video controls are not accessible (although, clicking on the video itself will start/stop it.  Fullscreen and volume controls are inaccessible).  Any way around this?  And, to keep the video from automatically starting (assuming the play button can be made accessible)?

and...

Comment: 3) If you browse my source at http://www.59plymouth.net/fancybox/fancybox.html, you'll see that I fully qualified the href in the commented line for the local video.  This still does not get added to the gallery - but, the YouTube video does.  Why is that?